# Dimension not selectable in Wave. Bug or feature?

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics

I have created a dataset using Data Builder, which has the following structure:

```
Measurement (cust.obj.) <- Asset <- Account
```

I want to group by a certain Account attribute. The dimensions that Wave lets me select are Measurement and Asset attributes. Not Account attributes. Why is that? Is it a bug or a feature? Do I need to do something special to be able to select an attribute in a parent-parent-object?

The documentation on Wave and Analytics does not have much to say on this.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes you can select Dimensions (Attributes) from Asset and Account.

If you are unable to it is normally one of two things.  Either the field used to relate Asset to Account is not the correct one (IE maybe more than one lookup from Asset to Account) or the lookup data is missing on some/many/all of the Asset records.

Wave will suppress records that don't have a dimension if that dimension is selected as opposed to showing them as null.

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/bi_admin_guide_data_integration_guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Verify if the Account field is of type Text or Date, the fields number are measurable and do not qualify as Dimension, the text and date fields can be used as dimension.